# How to refresh an activity with old intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, refresh, onresume

I have 3 activities A,B, and C. Activity A is a login and passes the login to activity B, B is a list based on the login. Activity C is opened when when someone clicks on an item in the list from activity B and has a delete button to delete the item and goes back to activity B.  What I want to then do is just refresh Activity B with the intent originally passed from activity A.

Comment: I don't understand the problem...when you start Activity B, just save the intent's data somewhere (variables, SharedPreferences) and restore it when necessary

Comment: thanks was just having a bit of a mental block, could u explain to me what the difference of onResume and onRestart. Im confused to which i should be using

Comment: Personally I never had to use onRestart()...it is called before onStart() if the Activity was already created and stopped and then brought back again to the screen...you can see clearly the lifecycle here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html in the first graph